# Cannot open any database from sql server objects explorer in visual studio: it says login failed

Tags: sql-server, database, authentication

When I click to open a database icon it waits long time, then the icon becomes as it was unavailable. The error I got is that: I cannot login to database. Login failed.
Now I think it should use windows credential to login. Does this have to do because recently I changed my Microsoft account password btw?
No database that I created earlier can be opened and my application having connection string which use windows credential cannot access the database too.

Comment: Can you open an SQL Servers in SSMS with Windows Authentication?

Comment: My SSMS has an older version and cannot open it for this reason

Comment: Update it then. SSMS is a [separate download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15), currently at version 18.4. The Microsoft Account has nothing to do with SQL Server. `I think it should use windows credential` what *did* you use to add the server? That's what is used to connect. Did you test the connection when you added it? ie click on the `Test Connection` button, before clicking on OK?

Comment: Perhaps you used the wrong server name, or your account doesn't have permission to connect to that server. Or perhaps whoever added the account to the server didn't give it permission to connect to any of the databases

Comment: All these databases were created using entity framework using a connection string that allows windows authentication. Why does object explorer refuse to open them? Where are the settings to login stored in objects explorer?